# How to insert username if username does not exists using jQuery/php/AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I like to insert a new record if the username is not present in the database. 
The record is getting inserted but some unexpected things are happening with my code.

When I submit the button then I am able to insert new record but page is getting refresh and I am able to see a GET string in my URL ("url?username=user")

html code:

```
<form class="form-signin">
  <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Register</h2>
  <label for="inputUserName" class="sr-only">UserName</label>
  <input type="text" id="inputUserName" name ="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username" required autofocus>
  <br>
  <button onclick="saveData()" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

In the html code, I have onclick() which calls jquery

jQuery code:

```
function saveData() {
  var username = $('#inputUserName').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'usersave.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {name: username},
    success: function (data) {
      $('#register').prepend(data);
      viewData();
    }
  });
}
```

`viewData()` is another jQuery function in which I am selecting all data from a table to display the data.

php code:

```
include './common/db_connect.php';
$db_connection = db_connect();
if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])) {
  $user_name = trim(strtolower($_POST['name']));
  $select_query = "SELECT user_id, username, admin, active FROM user WHERE username = ? AND active = 1";
  $query = $db_connection->prepare($select_query);
  $query->bindParam(1, $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->execute();
  $result = $query->fetch();
  if(empty($result)) {
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO user (username) VALUES (?)";
    $query = $db_connection->prepare($insert_query);
    $query->bindParam(1, $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    echo '<p id="message" class="alert alert-success">User is added</p>';
  } else {
    echo '<p id="message" class="alert alert-danger">Username already exits. 
   Please select a different one.</p>';
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on why these unexpected things are happening?

Is there a better way to check if a user is present or not in the db. 
If it is then insert into db. All this via AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean your page is getting inadvertently refreshed, try removing type="submit" from the button.

Answer (score 0):

see if this might help you change your `saveData` to a submit listener for the form, and more importantly you have to `return false` after AJAX call.

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function () {  
  var username = $('#inputUserName').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'usersave.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {name: username},
    success: function (data) {
      $('#register').prepend(data);
      viewData();
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

and remove `onclick="saveData()"` attribute from the submit button

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I believe that the refresh issue is related to the nature of SUBMIT button on the form.

I personally am not a fan of onClick functions so i would suggest you do something like this.

change your form to this

```
<form class="form-signin">
  <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Register</h2>
  <label for="inputUserName" class="sr-only">UserName</label>
  <input type="text" id="inputUserName" name ="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username" required autofocus>
  <br>
  <a id="submitForm" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" >Register</a>
</form>
```

and in your js you can do something like this.

```
$('submitForm').click(function(event) {
    //this would avoid page refresh
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'usersave.php',
        type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
        dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
        data: {name: username},
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        //Do your magic here
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
});
```

> Another Note on your PHP Code:
>   I wouldn't personally do something like

```
    echo '<p id="message" class="alert alert-success">User is added</p>';
  } else {
    echo '<p id="message" class="alert alert-danger">Username already exits. 
   Please select a different one.</p>';
```

instead, echo something "true","ok","damnItsWorking" and then it would return it as `(data)` in `.done(function(data)` there have an if statement to display it.

it's just a suggestion, for your future debugging, not that you did it wrong, been there, done that, have the T-shirt.

> AND.... Use Promises instead :P